# Hbase Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop2, mapper, reducers

I am getting following error while transferring values from one Hbase table to other Hbase table. The code is working fine while transferring from Hbase table to file output.

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Driver Class:

```
        // Mapper
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
                mailsTable,
                scan,
                SimHashMapper.class,
                Text.class, Text.class,
                job);
        //reducer
        String targetTable="old_64bit";
       TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
                targetTable,        // output table
                SimHashReducer.class,    // reducer class
                job);
return job;
```

Mapper class is:

```
 public static class SimHashMapper extends
            TableMapper<Text, Text> {

        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value,
                Context context) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                         .......
           context.write(new Text(s),new Text(t));
```

Reducer class is:

```
public static class SimHashReducer extends
            TableReducer<Text, Text,ImmutableBytesWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Text values, //values is a single Text value
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(values.toString()));
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("64_bit_fingerprint"),Bytes.toBytes(""),Bytes.toBytes(values.toString()));
            //context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("old_64bit")),put);

           context.write(null, put);
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

your function codes:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Text values, //values is a single Text value
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, //values is a single Text value
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```